# The role of BeginInit() and EndInit() methods in Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've red that those methods of `ISupportInitialize` interface are used by Designer to support optimization, to ensure atomicity of initialization of controls, and to prevent any action on controls during initialization. My questions are:

1. In what way they help Designer to optimize initialization of controls?
2. Why to ensure atomicity of initialization?
3. Is there any reasonable example when to use them in code not generated by Designer?

Answer (score 10):

It does not have anything to do with optimization. `ISupportInitialize` is an interface that you need when your control is sensitive to the order in which properties are assigned.  There isn't any way to affect the order in which the designer assigns them, it does it alphabetically.

You typically set a *bool* variable to true in your `BeginInit()` method, you test this in the property setters and don't do anything when it is set.  Your `EndInit()` method then makes the property values effective.

You can see a good example of this in the [ErrorProvider component](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ErrorProvider.cs,639).  Note how it uses the methods to defer data binding.  The [PictureBox control](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,1417) is another good example, it uses it to defer image downloading.  [TrackBar](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TrackBar.cs,42aa0229e40f655b) is yet another example, it uses it to ensure that the `Value` property is between Minimum and Maximum.  Etcetera, the .NET Framework source is often a very good place to see how .NET types are used in practice.

Comment: So you're saying that `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` are putting properties in alphabetical order in Designer? How order of properties could affect a control?

Comment: No, you missed that by a mile.  No idea how to explain it better or to give more examples of usage.  Just leave it on the shelf, you'll discover why you need it sooner or later.

Comment: Basically, if your control is unable to cope with properties being set in an arbitrary (alphabetical) order, or needs to know when *all* of the properties have finished being set, this is how you do it.

Answer (score -1):

By definition the Designer permits to create controls in a visual mode, the appropriate code to initialize the controls is then generated by Visual Studio.

The initialization is done in one place to avoid any null reference issue later in your code. You expect indeed every controls already created when you use their reference.

You perfectly can create your controls initialization if for example you want to dynamically create your interface based on a specific constructor.