# How can I use performance counter without using a timer in c # form? I get an error like Category name is not found

Tags: c#, progress-bar, performancecounter

While writing a video converter program in c # form, I measure the convert speed with the progress bar. I am actually measuring using certain techniques, but I want to give the user how much CPU he uses with the actual values, that is, the speed of the process.

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "mp3")
                {
                  var convert = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
                    convert.ConvertMedia(VideoPath, MusicPath, "mp3");
                    progressBar1.Value = (int)(performanceCounter1.NextValue());
                    label7.Text = "Processor Time: " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
                    /*   progressBar1.Value = 80;
                        label7.Text = "% 80";*/
                    MessageBox.Show("converst is okey");
                    progressBar1.Value = (int)(performanceCounter1.NextValue());
                    label7.Text = "Processor Time: " + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
```

I did this with the code I found from inetnet, but I am failing.
[image: ro]
How can I fix?

In this pictures,

[image]

Comment: do you also have begininit like `((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.performanceCounter1)).BeginInit();`

Comment: No it has not. Am ı add?

Comment: check this out, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: hey Zeynep, did the link help you, let me know if you need more help

Comment: Hi Clint, Since this is not my only project, I could not examine in detail. I will definitely ask for your help during the day :)

Comment: Although I add the code you said, I get the same error again. When I was designing the video converter before, I wrote the information of the last page that came out to one of the textboxes by default. For example, if the program got out of the T folder, it would bring this default information again when it was running exe. Could the error have something to do with it? @clint

Comment: I wrote codes on program.cs page. I don't know, when I said Category name is not found, this came to my mind first. @clint

Comment: can you clarify once again, what is that you are trying to achieve

Comment: I am writing C # video converter software. I want to observe and measure the converting speed of the video with the progress bar. For this purpose, I wrote a code like I compiled above. But after adding the performance counter in the code, I got the error in the picture and made a mistake before the program started. I wrote the code you added, but the error did not change. @Clint

Comment: okay understood, so basically in your UI the progress bar shows how much % of video conversion is complete, and along with that you want to also calculate the performance of CPU using performance counter, and you want to display CPU performance on a textbox real time ?

Comment: Yess, definitely @Clint

Comment: let me know if the below solution answers your query ;)

Comment: I did but it was giving same error.

Comment: you can remove lines for `System.ComponentMode.ISupportInitialize`, its not required, in my post below, you can look at HansPassants note in `ISupportInitialize` for more info

Comment: I looking back. And its working. But, it has a problem. Actually There is not a big problem but, its like bug. I am renewing questions pictures. Please look at this.

Comment: @Zeynet, sure Ill take a look after u upload

Comment: And, progress bar value must be 1 - 100 but in this pictures value, different type.

Comment: I'm looking at your pics, can you please tell me what the bug is ?

Comment: Do you see ınput textbox, Must be an int value between 1 and 100. this value must be the progress value of the progress bar and int value.
At the same time, when the progress bar is 100 stuffed, the progress bar is as if it is doing more than one operation, it is full and empty until the process is completed.

Comment: Ideally the input textbox should be just a display to show performance counter  and this should not correspond how you measure the progress in `progress bar`. Hope it is clear ?

Comment: So how do I convert the value of the progress bar, that is, the value that shows the instant cpu speed, to an int value? because it's actually the part that will work for me.

Comment: If the idea is to show the CPU speed in real time, progress bar is NOT the right UI control to display that. You can use a TextBox  to show the CPU speed in real time and progress bar can continue to measure the estimated time to finish the activity

Comment: basically what I really wanted to measure was video convert speed. But if I couldn't do it properly, I wanted to compare the amount of CPU usage. because those who want to improve this from me want to check the status of the transaction through the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we initialize the the relevant CPU counters that you want to capture, and on `ButtonClick` we start to read the performance counter and increment the progress bar. The *forloop* and *progressbar* increments may not be relevant in your case but I added it to demonstrate the whole scenario

As per your clarification on comments section, this will update the textbox with the real time information from the performanceCounters

```
public PerformanceCounter privateBytes;
public PerformanceCounter gen2Collections;
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
    privateBytes =  new PerformanceCounter(categoryName: "Process", counterName: "Private Bytes", instanceName: currentProcess);
    gen2Collections = new PerformanceCounter(categoryName: ".NET CLR Memory", counterName: "# Gen 2 Collections", instanceName: currentProcess);

}
async Task LongRunningProcess()
{

    await Task.Delay(500);

}
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = i;
        textBox1.Text = "privateBytes:" + privateBytes.NextValue().ToString() + " gen2Collections:" + gen2Collections.NextValue().ToString() ;
        await Task.Run(() => LongRunningProcess());
    }

}
```

*Note: Also Check Hans Passant's answer on [ISupportInitialize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464280/4686729)*