Designer property initialization order
I have a user control with two properties that are relevant for my current problem. int NumberOfColumns and string AssignedLabels. NumberOfColumns configures the columncount of a tablelayoutpanel. AssignedLabels will be a CRLF separated string to assign values to the labels contained in the TableLayoutPanel. When the AssignedLabels string is split by CRLF and the number of array-items does not match the current value of NumberOfColumns no assignments are made.
The designer serializes everything alphabetically... so AssignedLabels will go first and NumbersOfColumns second. The default value for NumberOfColumns is 8.
If I set the number of columns to 2 in the designer and assign to labels to it, it will be serialized correctly:
x.AssignedLabels = "Yes\r\nNo";
x.NumberOfColumns = 2;

But when its deserialized, the AssignedLabels property is read first, and at that time the NumberOfColumns is still the default value (8) and therefore no assignments will be made as the splitted string does not match the column count.
Of course I could rename the NumberOfColumns to something like AaaaaaaNumberOfColumns so it will be serialized first, but thats a bit hacky. Are there any attributes to control the serialization order or another more transparent approach to solve this problem?

I think what you are looking for is ISupportInitialize read more on the Docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize?view=net-8.0
It's made to allow you to control the initialization process for components, especially if certain properties depend on each other and need to be initialized in a specific order.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464280/106159
